# code stopped working after upgrading jquery library to version 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following piece of jquery code for displaying a loading.gif when the user has clicked on a link/button on a page.

```
<div class="progress-indicator">
  <img src="/myapplication/images/loading.gif" alt=""  />
</div>


<script>
  $j(window).bind(
           $j.browser.opera ? 'unload' : 'beforeunload',
           function(){
              //display image container
              $j('.progress-indicator').css( 'display', 'block' );
              //set a little timeout and force re-displaying of the image
              //this can work around IE behavior, that 'freezes'
              //animations during a submit
              setTimeout( function() {
                  $j('.progress-indicator > img').attr( 'src',
                  $j('.progress-indicator > img').attr('src')+'?reload' );
              }, 50 );
            } );
</script>
```

It was working great with 'jquery version 1.5.1', until I upgraded jquery to version 1.10.0. The code no longer works.

Can anyone please help me with it? Thanks a lot for all your help and suggestions.

Comment: you have a typo `$j('.progress-indicator > img').attr( 'src',` <<<< missing the closing );

Comment: Read the upgrade notes, do not just swap versions and expect everything to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.browser()` was removed in jQuery 1.9

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

You should use the jQuery Migrate plugin to check your scripts when upgrading.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin

Comment: Rightfully so! Feature detection is a much better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [upgrade guide](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

[1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme): http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ and [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Try looking for the problem